# Marker detection on paper sheet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, detection, marker

Currently I am looking for a simple way to **detect the position of markers on a photographed paper sheet using Javascript**. All I've found so far are libraries which are a bit over the top for my purpose.

For example **awe.js** uses AR technology to detect markers on live videos. However, all I need is a marker detection on a picture, as can be seen on the uploaded example file below. (Note that the markers are just dummy markers. I am going to use individual markers for every corner)

[Paper sheet with 4 dummy markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yeLc.jpg)

Libraries I tried:

- awe.js
- js-aruco
- OpenCV: not for Javascript
- tracking.js: https://trackingjs.com/examples/brief.html (doesn`t work 
  very well)

Does anybody know a simple solution for my problem?

Comment: What do you need to detect about the marker? Their type, position?

Comment: Their position. I`d like to dewarp the photo perspectively with help of the markers. The dewarping works great when I manually click on the markers, but I want this process to happen automatically.

Comment: tracking.js allows to implement your own variation - I would use that. the example you linked uses blur techniques and that is most likely not going to work for what you want.
https://trackingjs.com/docs.html#custom-tracker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to find a solution for my problem. After all, I managed to detect the markers of my paper sheet with js-aruco:

https://github.com/jcmellado/js-aruco/tree/master/samples/getusermedia

js-aruco makes a snapshot of a live video, renders each of the snapshots in a canvas and detects the markers.
I adjusted the „getusermedia.html“ so that it doesn't take a snapshot from a video but renders an image only once in the canvas. The detector is able to find each of the markers listed on this page:

http://diogok.net/js-aruco-markers/index.html

Finally, I had to rewrite the function from aruco.js, so that it finds markers that are smaller than 20% of the paper (which was the default value).

```
AR.Detector.prototype.detect = function(image) {
  CV.grayscale(image, this.grey);
  CV.adaptiveThreshold(this.grey, this.thres, 2, 3);
  this.contours = CV.findContours(this.thres, this.binary);
  this.candidates = this.findCandidates(this.contours, image.width * 0.01, 0.05, 10);
  this.candidates = this.clockwiseCorners(this.candidates);
  this.candidates = this.notTooNear(this.candidates, 10);
  return this.findMarkers(this.grey, this.candidates, 49);
};
```

This way, js-aruco is able to find small markers on the corners of my paper sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have custom markers in your image or must perform the markers detection on server side, you can use the [js-aruco2](https://github.com/damianofalcioni/js-aruco2) library.
Here you are not forced to use the ArUco markers (not much reliables due to the min hamming distance of 1) but can use the more advanced ARUCO_MIP_36h12 (also provided by the ArUco Teams in their C++ library and with an hamming distance of 12), or you can create your own markers list in the following way:

```
AR.DICTIONARIES.MyDictionary = {
  nBits: 25, //bit dimension of the markers in your dictionary
  tau: 1,    //optional hamming distance of the codes in your dictionary
  codeList: ['0x1084210UL', '0x1084217UL', ...] //hexadecimal representation of every marker in your dictionary, where the array order represent the marker id
};
```